# IntelliJ Idea advanced search for key word in the classes containing a certain word

Tags: java, search, intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2017.3.

I use often <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find in path any text anwhere and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to find any class by name.

Is there a way to combine this search for a text inside a group of classes containing a certain word in its name?

---

Here is an example for clarity:

In a huge project, I want to find all classes which contains a word e.g. `transformation` as whatsoever (variable, method name, String...), but these classes must contain another word e.g. `xml` in its name. The results would be e.g.:

- Interface `XmlFile` with a method `void completeTransformation()`
- Class `MyLittleXmlClass` which works with a String variable with `"transformation"` value
- Class `MyBigXmlClass` which implements `XmlFile` and has method `void completeTransformation()`
- Class `XmlDocument` which has a variable named `transformationVariable`
- etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Find in path and use an additional file mask. The file mask also accepts asterisks as shown in the image below:
  [image: Find in Path with asterisk]

Answer (score 2):

You could use file mask to filter the name in the file. In your case you could search for `*Xml*.*`(This will search file which contains any Xml keyword in the file name with any kind of extension) in file mask field and combine this search with the normal keyword search `transformation`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not handled perfectly, but by using the regex option in the `Find in Path` menu, you can do the following:

```
(?s)^(?=.*?SWAGGER)(?=.*?configure)(?=.*?antMatchers)
```

This would match a file that has the word `SWAGGER`, `configure` and `antMatchers`.

The problem is that it shows every line in the file as a result.

In your case, you could try the following for:

> Class `MyBigXmlClass` which implements `XmlFile` and has method `void completeTransformation()`

```
(?s)^(?=.*?MyBigXmlClass)(?=.*?XmlFile)(?=.*?completeTransformation)
```

#### UPDATE

This works in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2017.1.2

Answer (score 1):

This is possible using the [structurally search function](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace-examples.html)